# AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'APIConnectionError'

Tags: attributeerror, openai-api

I tried to use GPT openai to translate Korean to English.
My text data is a type of list which includes more than 3000 sentences, so I updated payment method and also utilize "backoff" library for requesting error; however, end up with APIConnectionError. In the purpose of getting the result ASPS, I would like to "try & except", but it still give me an error messege, "AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'APIConnectionError". Please help me out!

```
import backoff
import pandas as pd
import openai
import os
import tiktoken
import re
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


tag_df = pd.read_csv('/wo_employee_post.csv')
tag_df = pd.DataFrame(tag_df.contents.dropna())#.contents.str.contains('\$')
tag_list = tag_df[tag_df.contents.str.contains('\$')].contents

def text_cleaning(doc):
    doc = re.sub("[^ㄱ-ㅎㅏ-ㅣ가-힣 ]", "", doc)
    doc = re.sub("[\{\}\[\]\/?.,;:|\)*~`!^\-_+<>@\#$%&\\\=\(\'\"]", " ", doc)

    return doc

clean_tag = []
for tag in tag_list:
    clean_tag.append(text_cleaning(tag))


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "hidden"
print(os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"))
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")


@backoff.on_exception(backoff.expo, openai.error.RateLimitError)
def translate(text, engine="text-davinci-002"):
    p = f'Transform this sentence from korean to english: {text}'
        
    # generate the response
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine=engine,
        prompt=p,
        temperature=.7,
        #max_tokens=5000,
        top_p=1,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0,
        stop=["12."]
    )

    return response['choices'][0]['text']


tag_in_eng = []
for tag in clean_tag:
    try: 
        tag_in_eng.append(translate(tag))
    
    except openai.APIConnectionError:
        continue
```

---

## error detail

---

ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
702             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 703             httplib_response = self._make_request(
704                 conn,

34 frames
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

APIConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
4         tag_in_eng.append(translate(tag))
5
----> 6     except openai.APIConnectionError:
7         continue

AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'APIConnectionError'

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

`except openai.APIConnectionError:`
to
`except openai.error.APIConnectionError:`
then everything should work.

Comment: Even after adding timeout param in Openai call. It's going on long hold. I get this exception after 5 to 10 minutes. How to solve this?